# Java Date Formatting ParseException

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I have a String as `Friday, August 01, 2014`. I want to format this and show as `2014-08-01`.

I have tried this. but this gave `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Friday, August 01, 2014"`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MM d, yyyy");
String dateInString = "Friday, August 01, 2014";
Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
System.out.println(date);
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the [SimpleDateFormat API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) as it's all well explained there.

Note this explanation from the API:

> - **Text**: For formatting, if the number of pattern letters is 4 or more, the full form is used; otherwise a short or abbreviated form is used if available. For parsing, both forms are accepted, independent of the number of pattern letters.
> - **Number**: For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields.

So for instance, MM corresponds to a numeric month, not the month name. For the complete month name, I'd use `MMMM`, and for the complete week name, I'd use `EEEE`. I'd use `dd` for a two digit date such as 01.

e.g.,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
```